# Format a Range to 7 numbers long, adding preceding "0"

Tags: excel, vba

Can't seem to get this one to work. I have code that copies data from a workbook to another. What I want it to do is - after it copies the data across, the range is then formatted to text (to allow preceding zero's) and formatted to 7 characters long - where additional zero's added in front to make up the character count (hope that makes sense).

Example: If the Number is 1234 it will format as 0001234

Can anyone help me with this? This is what I've tried so far..

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
       Range("B9").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll



    Range("B9", Range("B8").End(xlDown)).Select
    If Not Selection.HasFormula Then
Selection = Selection.Value
Selection.NumberFormat = "Custom"
Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000000"
End If
```

Comment: Above should work not unless your cell value is `Text`. And you say you formatted it as text. Do you want to just change the format or you really want to create a string 7 characters long.

Comment: Thanks @L42 I need to get this data formatted to 7 characters long with preceding "0" as exampled above. It just does not work with this code.

Comment: Your code should work again if the actual cell value is not text value.

Comment: Thanks again @L42 but it doesn't work which is why I am asking for help. The source data is "text" I try converting to Number or Custom and formatting as per selection.numberformat however the data still copies across as it is in the source data, without the added data manipulation I want i.e. adding the preceding zero's

Comment: `Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000": Selection.Value = Selection.Value`

Comment: Thank you @Rory this solved my problem - greatly appreciate your time in responding mate.

Comment: @Rory I think that better go to answer :). OP just needs to format that entries, not alter it to 7 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that your data is currently text, all you need to do is alter the cell format and then effectively re-enter the data, which you can do like this:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000"
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
```

Comment: You're a legend Rory, simple and effective - thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your comments, you can try this:

```
Dim helper As Range
With Sheet1
    Set helper = .Range("B8", .Range("B8").End(xlDown)).Offset(, 1)
    'if you choose to offset by 2 columns, using column D instead as helper
    'change [-1] in below formula to [-2]
    helper.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""0000000"")"
    helper.Copy: .Range("B8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    helper.ClearContents
End With
```

Note, this will use the next column C as helper column.
 Adjust it to any empty column of your choice.

Comment: Thank you @L42 for this, I truly appreciate it. This worked great however there was a lot of change I needed to make to my code, the response from Rory was a 1-liner which solved the problem - if I was writing from scratch your code would have been fantastic to have on hand so again, appreciate your time and effort mate.

Comment: @JaysonD No problem. I thought you need a resulting 7 character length data (Text format), not just formatted so I came up with above. I'll leave it here just in case it's useful to others :)